# What's the appropriate Sage syntax to modify edge / vertex border thickness of a graph?

Tags: python, sage

Sage is outstanding, in particular for graph theory. But actually I cannot find examples of how to change edge or vertex border thickness.

I've read [this documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html) without success:

I'm using this:

```
import sage.graphs.graph_plot
G = graphs.Grid2dGraph(4,4)
P = G.graphplot(vertex_labels=False, vertex_size=700, graph_border=False, edge_thickness=10)
P.show()
```

... but Sage still does not recognize the `edge_thickness` option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The requested feature works since Sage 7.3, thanks to

- [Sage trac ticket #20035: Enable thickness-option in graph plotting](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/20035)

If you are running an older version of Sage, consider upgrading.
Each new version brings improvements and bug fixes.

Using one of the latest versions of Sage:

```
sage: version()
'SageMath version 8.2.rc2, Release Date: 2018-04-10'
```

the `edge_thickness` parameter makes a noticeable difference.

Without specifying `edge_thickness`:

```
sage: import sage.graphs.graph_plot
sage: G = graphs.Grid2dGraph(4,4)
sage: P = G.graphplot(vertex_labels=False, vertex_size=700, graph_border=False)
sage: P.show()
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 25 graphics primitives
```

[image: Grid graph with edge_thickness=1]

Specifying `edge_thickness=10`:

```
sage: P = G.graphplot(vertex_labels=False, vertex_size=700, graph_border=False, edge_thickness=10)
sage: P.show()
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 25 graphics primitives
```

[image: Grid graph with edge_thickness=10]

Specifying `edge_thickness=1` (same as default):

```
sage: P = G.graphplot(vertex_labels=False, vertex_size=700, graph_border=False, edge_thickness=1)
sage: P.show()
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 25 graphics primitives
```

[image: Grid graph with edge_thickness=1]